# Using external NTFS drive from windows on mac with bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, external-disk, ntfs

I am new to StackExchange so please pardon, if my request does not follow all best practices.

My dad uses Windows 10 on a MacBook pro 2015 via Bootcamp. His backup data is on an external NTFS hard drive. He is unable to access the data.

I am using NTFS with mac via paragon software. I.e. I am aware of the different file types.

What I am struggling with is that, since he is running bootcamp, he is probably not able to use a paragon NTFS driver for mac, is he?

Is this a know issue? Can somebody advise on how to approach this? Happy to buy a Software like the Paragon driver, if that solves the quest.

Comment: Windows 10 installed on a Mac does not need a third party driver in order to read an external NTFS hard drive. Can I assume this hard drive is connect through a USB port?

Comment: Turns out you are right. Misunderstanding btw. my dad and myself. Hard drive was not really 'empty'. He just did not see the files. Thank you. Case is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 installed on a Mac does not need a third party driver in order to read an external NTFS hard drive (question was based on wrong perception). Thank you to David Anderson